# how to get line number (not current page)

Tags: vba, ms-word

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYDNu.png)

as shown in the picture, the line number of my selection range should be **848**, but I use code `Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)` get return value is **1** (*maybe this code only return the current page line number?*)

now I want to use some way to get the return value **848**, how I can do?

Comment: I'm afraid what you're asking isn't clear. You want a line number, but it's not clear how the code should know the location of this line in order to get the number? You need to provide more context, possibly with code to provide the starting point for this context.

Comment: @CindyMeister Sorry, I have updated the question and hope to get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the first line of the next section then the following should work.

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToNext
Selection.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
```